# PHP array count values and output new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 2
        )

)
```

I am trying to count the values and output a new array that looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 1
        )
)
```

I have tried to get the count by doing this...

```
print_r(array_count_values($myarray));
```

But this is not working for me, is there a way to count the values and creaye the new array all in one statement?

Comment: `array_count_values` works on *one* array. You have an *array of arrays*. You need some sort of loop here. Hint: `array_map`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @deceze advised - it is:

```
// applying `array_count_values` to each element of `$array`
print_r(array_map('array_count_values', $array));
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. How would I go about making this a new array instead of just outputting it with print_r?

Comment: @fightstarr20 Just assign the result to a new variable `$newArray = array_map('array_count_values', $initialArray);`

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but you need to apply `array_count_values()` to each subarray, not the parent array.

```
$arr = [
    'item1' => [1, 1, 3],
    'item2' => [1, 1, 1, 2, 1],
    'item3' => [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
];

$totals = array_map('array_count_values', $arr);

print_r($totals);
```

Results in

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
            [3] => 1
        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 1
        )

    [item3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 6
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have array into an another array, it means you can't use `array_count_values()` with this way, either use `array_map()` or use `foreach` and save data into one another array like:

```
<?php
$array = array(
      'item1'=>array(1,1,1),
      'item2'=>array(1,1,1,1,1,2)
  );

$newArray = array(); // your new array
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $newArray[$key] = array_count_values($value);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [item1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
        )

    [item2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```